# Automatically taken out of AD domain

Tags: active-directory

arrived to work this morning just to find that I couldn't log on to my computer.
As it turned out my computer had been "unjoined" from our domain.
I am positive that I didn't "unjoin" manually yesterday before I closed the computer down.

Have anyone experienced this behavior before and is it even possible? Or should I start getting nervous about anyone playing around on the serverside?

I'm running my domaincontroller on a Windows2003 server and the client computer that got "unjoined" is a Windows 7 Ultimate.

Edit:
The computer account remained, I know I was unjoined because when I logged in with a local computer account I was suddenly in a workgroup. Rejoined and everything went back to normal, same profile and everything.

Comment: Do you mean that your machine had been removed from the domain in an orderly manner, or do you mean the workstation still thought it was part of the domain, but the domain had no knowledge of you (or vice-versa)?

Comment: Thancks for all the rplies guys, I was kinda "hoping" it would happen again soon or that anyone had experienced the same thing before. I've been working with AD domains for some years now and never seen this before. It was my own work PC so I know there hasn't been any anomalies lately with logging on and such, I'm gonna close this issue now and just wait and see if it happens again, I couldn't find anything in the logs, not on the PC nor the server so the search will stop for now.

Once again, thx for the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that somebody else didn't unjoin you? Take a look at the event logs on the machine to see if somebody/something else did this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone deleted your computer account in the domain by accident;)?

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it was 'unjoined' ?  are you simply having auth failures all over the place?

Is it just your machine?

Is the clock wrong? (perhaps the BIOS battery failed and reverted the date?)

Answer (score 0):

check the event log - system and security sections are likely places but check application as well

an outside possibility is that for some reason your workstation hasn't been talking to the DC for quite a while now (and you've been logging on with cached credentials) and the "time a computer is allowed to be on the domain without talking to a DC" value was exceeded